# Como remover nomes duplicados em linhas de um dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, pessoal.

Tenho o seguinte dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Codigo': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Nomes': ['Alan Silva, Alan Silva', 'Carlos Santos, Carlos Santos', 'Joao Pedro', ' João Pedro'],
})
df

    Codigo  Nomes
0   1   Alan Silva, Alan Silva
1   2   Carlos Santos, Carlos Santos
2   3   Joao Pedro
3   4   João Pedro
```

Existe alguma forma de remover os nomes duplicados? A saída que eu preciso é:

```
Codigo  Nomes
0   1   Alan Silva
1   2   Carlos Santos
2   3   Joao Pedro
3   4   João Pedro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vejo aqui dois casos distintos:

- Caso 1: Todo valor de `Nomes` que possuir o delimitador `vírgula (,)` é **obrigatoriamente** repetido
- Caso 2: Os valores de `Nomes` que possuir vírgula não é necessariamente nome repetido.

### Soluções

#### Caso 1

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Codigo': [1, 2, 3, 4],'Nomes': ['Alan Silva, Alan Silva', 'Carlos Santos, Carlos Santos', 'Joao Pedro', ' João Pedro']})

df['Nomes'] = df['Nomes'].apply(lambda nome: nome.split(',')[0])
```

#### Caso 2

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Codigo': [1, 2, 3, 4],'Nomes': ['Alan Silva, Alan Silva', 'Carlos Santos, Carlos Santana', 'Joao Pedro', ' João Pedro']})

>>> df
   Codigo                          Nomes
0       1         Alan Silva, Alan Silva
1       2  Carlos Santos, Carlos Santana     # Repare que o segundo é Santana
2       3                     Joao Pedro
3       4                     João Pedro
```

Para este caso, defina uma função que verifique se o nome é igual e retorne o valor correto.

```
def verifica_repetido(nomes):
    l_nomes = nomes.split(",")
    if len(l_nomes) == 1:
        return nomes
    if l_nomes[0].lstrip().rstrip() == l_nomes[1].lstrip().rstrip():
        return l_nomes[0]
    return nomes
```

Depois faça como da primeira vez, mas aplicando a função.

```
df['Nomes'] = df['Nomes'].apply(verifica_repetido)
```

**Nota** Você pode fazer a mesma coisa com a função nomeada que fez com `lambda`

Comment: Perfeito! As duas solução atendem perfeitamente. Obrigado